# why do the large industrial lathes, 1 HP upwards still use induction motor and not BLDC?

Tags: brushless-dc-motor

I'm trying to find an answer as to why exactly larger more powerful lathes still have 3 phase AC induction motor. All the benefits of a BLDC seem to far outweigh the use of an induction and they seem to be relatively cheap if bought separately.

Comment: Cost, cost, and cost.  Induction motors are way cheaper than BLDC motors + drive.

Comment: Almost all large fixed motors are induction machines.  For a machine tool application, there's also a relatively seamless upgrade path from running on the 3-phase mains, to speed control via a vector drive which is a close cousin to a BLDC drive.  While there are motors optimized specifically for VFD use, *legacy* equipment will run on a VFD over some range on each side of mains frequency.

Comment: I've been considering considering this for a smallish olde lathe. A several kW BLDCM is around $150 + from Asia. An ESC to suit is about the same. Now you need some form of control electronics. If off the shelf - add a case, power supply, software, ... . Now add local market markup. How does a say 2-3 HP induction motor compare in price?

Comment: magnets are expensive. induction motors require none. BLDC's advantage is power for weight, but lathes arent mobile so it doesnt matter

Comment: The only possible advantage to the BLDC is speed control with a drive. This "could" eliminate the gearbox that most lathes use. The drawback is that a BLDC has terrible torque at low RPM unless a **very** large drive is used. Most large lathes operate at low RPM and the cost of such a drive and motor combo would outweigh a gear box.

Answer (score 1):

There could be many reasons that they dont want to switch to BLDC motors.

- Motor cost: the AC induction motor might cheaper than BLDC motors for their application
- Engineering cost: They dont have the expertise or want to develop the expertise to drive BLDC motors. BLDC motors can be complicated to implement depending on what application the motor is being used for.
- competition: Why spend all the time and resources converting to BLDC if none of your competitors are doing it. most customers dont care what type of motor that their lathe uses as long as it can do everything(efficiency, noise, weight) just as well as the competing product.
- knowing: They dont know that BLDC motors will be better for their application. This is what BLDC motor sales people are looking for.

Everything comes down to where you want to spend your resource(Time, Money) and spending resources on developing a different motor system might be better spend on adding other features to lathes.